# War to home base

Tags: clash-of-clans

Is there a way to copy my war base to my home base in clash of clans? I know there is for home to war base but I want to copy my war to my home base.

Comment: No, there's none. Usually though, your home base is more likely to be more upgraded because your war base isn't updated when you get new buildings.

Answer (score 2):

No, as you stated, you can only transfer your home base to war base. Not vice versa.

Source: Being in 50+ clan wars and a leader of a clan that wars non-stop.

Comment: Do you have a source for this information?